# S-Video has no color output for cx231xx

Tags: linux, video

I've got an Elgato Video Capture V2 capture card I'd like to use for capturing S-Video. Sadly, when I use tvime to capture, the output is shown in black and white. I tested this using cheese as well, and the output was also black and white. Plugging S-Video into my television gives me full color.

Here's my dmesg when I start the capture:

```
[ 1481.271451] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_stop_stream():: ep_mask = 8
[ 1594.616110] cx231xx #0:  setPowerMode::mode = 48, No Change req.
[ 1594.638896] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_dif_set_standard: setStandard to ffffffff
[ 1594.683447] cx231xx #0: video_mux : 0
[ 1594.683450] cx231xx #0: do_mode_ctrl_overrides : 0x1000
[ 1594.684200] cx231xx #0: do_mode_ctrl_overrides NTSC
[ 1594.697050] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_stop_stream():: ep_mask = 8
[ 1594.697271] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_initialize_stream_xfer: set video registers
[ 1594.697393] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_start_stream():: ep_mask = 8
[ 1594.715842] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_dif_set_standard: setStandard to ffffffff
[ 1594.761930] cx231xx #0: video_mux : 1
[ 1594.761931] cx231xx #0: do_mode_ctrl_overrides : 0x1000
[ 1594.762680] cx231xx #0: do_mode_ctrl_overrides NTSC
[ 1597.492394] cx231xx #0: cx231xx_stop_stream():: ep_mask = 8
```

Also,

```
$ tvtime -v

Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/llldino/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
cpuinfo: CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4690K CPU @ 3.50GHz, family 6, model 12, stepping 3.
cpuinfo: CPU measured at 184296045375450.094MHz.
tvtime: Cannot set priority to -10: Permission denied.
xcommon: Display :0.0, vendor The X.Org Foundation, vendor release 11604000
xfullscreen: Using XINERAMA for dual-head information.
xfullscreen: Pixels are square.
xfullscreen: Number of displays is 2.
xfullscreen: Head 0 at 0,0 with size 1920x1080.
xfullscreen: Head 1 at 1920,0 with size 1920x1080.
xcommon: Have XTest, will use it to ping the screensaver.
xcommon: Pixel aspect ratio 1:1.
xcommon: Pixel aspect ratio 1:1.
xcommon: Window manager is Xfwm4 and is EWMH compliant.
xcommon: Using EWMH state fullscreen property.
xcommon: Using EWMH state above property.
xcommon: Using EWMH state below property.
xcommon: Pixel aspect ratio 1:1.
xcommon: Displaying in a 768x576 window inside 768x576 space.
xvoutput: Using XVIDEO adaptor 601: NV17 Video Texture.
speedycode: Using MMXEXT optimized functions.
station: Reading stationlist from /home/llldino/.tvtime/stationlist.xml
videoinput: Using video4linux2 driver 'cx231xx', card 'Elgato Video Capture V2' (bus usb-0000:00:14.0-10).
videoinput: Version is 200711, capabilities 85000011.
videoinput: Can't get tuner info: Inappropriate ioctl for device
videoinput: Maximum input width: 720 pixels.
videoinput: Can't get tuner info: Inappropriate ioctl for device
tvtime: Sampling input at 720 pixels per scanline.
mixer: Can't open device /dev/mixer, mixer volume and mute unavailable.
xcommon: Pixel aspect ratio 1:1.
xcommon: Displaying in a 768x576 window inside 768x576 space.
xcommon: Received a map, marking window as visible (60).
```

If anyone can help me out, I would very very much appreciate it. I'll give you permanent thanks on my Twitch page!

Comment: Are you using the `bttv` driver?

Comment: No, I'm using cx231xx

Answer (score 1):

I just had a struggle with my Elgato capture card outputting S-video as black and white.

I ended up switching the Elgato software settings to 'composite' instead of S-video and then changed the cable input so the yellow connection when into the red and it works perfectly now with colour!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're talking about using composite instead of S-Video, that's what I'm doing now. However I'd really like to be able to use S-Video

Comment: I can confirm black and white output with S-VIDEO,is a bug most probably

Comment: Using composite instead of s-video,or using composite adapter is not a solution,composite quality is poor comparing to s-video.